# New-Service in powershell does not accept AutomaticDelayedStart as StartupType

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I am trying to create through powershell a windows service with StartupType **AutomaticDelayedStart** . Unfortunately it seems like this kind of type is not accepted by powershell which wants only Boot, Syster, Automatic, Manual or Disabled. Is this a versioning problem by any chance? How can I get around this problem? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AutomaticDelayedStart` is only available with PS v6, older versions do not have this option.

You have to be careful which version of the documentation you look at, as it defaults to the latest version:

- [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=**powershell-5.1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-5.1)
- [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=**powershell-6**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-6)

As a workaround, you can use the command line `sc` to set this startup type:

```
sc.exe config ServiceName start= delayed-auto
```